Are JS exports singleton
class A {
}

export default new A(); 

Now, each time I import Class A across multiple files, would I be getting a new object or the same object ?
I had tested this locally, by importing this across multiple files, it seems to be returning the same object. But I would like to confirm if it is better to create an object of this class and then export it from the index file

I think that's true because exports are cached. Only the first import actually executes the code in the file. The rest simply extract the properties they want from the export object.

Generally yes. But please don't write code like this!
